# Adding variables to current context via a template tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'd like a template tag that fetches a queryset of objects and makes them available in the context of the current template. From what I can see this is possible with a simple_tag like so:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_myobject_queryset(context, string_arg)
    myobjects = MyObject.objects.all()
    context['myobjects'] = myobjects
    return ''
```

Are there any drawbacks with this method, or is there typically a better way to achieve what I want? I ask only because this feels slightly like a workaround to something I thought would be quite a commonplace task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider writing a context processor.

```
#myapp/contexts.py
def get_myobject_queryset(request):
    myobjects = MyObject.objects.all()
    return {'myobjects': myobjects}
```

Don't forget to add a processor to your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS settings.

```
#settings.py
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"myapp.contexts.get_myobject_queryset",)
```

Then in template you'll be able to access your variable like `{{ myobjects }}`

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

Comment: Ah, thanks this is the more sensible option I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You tag is fine, but you could use the [`assignment_tag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags) decorator instead.

Comment: This is also useful if I decide later I need to send string args with it, so thanks again.